# install bootstrap gem or yarn add bootstrap for rails 5.1 or both

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-5.1

After getting a project setup in rails 5.1 with --webpack=react option should I install the bootstrap gem? or use yarn add bootstrap? Or would I need both if I'm using rails and react components throughout a project?

Also, are there pros and cons of either method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on where you want to use Bootstrap.

In the case you need it, in a `app/views/*/*.html.erb` for instance, you would need the gem, and require it in the Rails assets pipeline in the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` and same for JavaScript file.

But as you mentioned you created your Rails application with `--webpack=react`, I guess you'd like to use Bootstrap in your client side application, so the `app/javascript` folder and not the Rails assets (`app/assets`).
In this case you will have to install it using `yarn`.

You have to see the `app/assets` as the "old way", or the non-javascript framework way (which isn't fully true as you have some gems to install React or AngularJs etc...), and you should see `app/javascript` the new way, with webpacker, so using a JavaScript framework and being an app 100% JavaScript (while in the assets you'll use some `.erb` files).